# Multiple rows Sql Server update using a Dedicated Table Value parameter - Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

Using the below stored procedure I am able to select a variable section of a table, given the Row index of each record. I tried to create another stored procedure similar to the `MulTselect`, only this time the table value parameter will have another column for the new value for a `MulTUpdate` stored procedure.

```
[RowIndex] int, [NewVal] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL
```

**the question is**, given the record - Rowindex and "NewValue", is it possible to do an **UPDATE** on multiple records like in select procedure below?

```
--sproc signature

CREATE Proc [dbo].[MulTSELECTViaRowIndexSpTVP] 
@SelectedTableName varchar (50),
@SelectedAction varchar(10),
@TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVPar dbo.TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVType READONLY


SET @CmdStr = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @SelectedTableName + ' 
               WHERE RowIndex in (SELECT RowIndex from @TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVPar);'

EXEC sp_executesql @CmdStr,N' @TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVPar dbo.TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVType READONLY',
         @TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVPar= @TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVPar
```

Comment: by also adding a `@SelectedColumnName` parameter

Comment: something like `SET @CmdStr = 'UPDATE ' + @SelectedTableName + ' SET ' + @SelectedColName + 'WHERE RowIndex in ...`

Answer (score 2):

AS I was looking through my old stored procedures i found one that stared me thinking in the right way, so this is what i got to compile, not yet tested.

```
Declare @TotalRec int = (Select COUNT(RowIndex) from @TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVPar);
Declare @Iter int =0, @Count int =0;
While @Iter < @TotalRec
     Begin
        Declare @curRowIndex int=
                (
                    select RowIndex from
                        (select row_number() over (order by RowIndex) as RowN,
                        * from  @TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVPar) T where T.RowN =(@Iter+1)
               );
        Declare @CurVal varchar(4000) = (Select [StrVal] from @TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVPar WHERE RowIndex=@curRowIndex);
        SET @CmdStr = 'UPDATE ' + @SelectedSDTOName + ' SET ' + @SelectedColName + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(@CurVal, '''') + ' WHERE RowIndex = ' + CAST(@curRowIndex as nvarchar);

        EXEC sp_executesql @CmdStr,N' @TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVPar dbo.TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVType READONLY',
                                 @TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVPar= @TestMulTiActMulTColIndexTVPar;
        Set @Iter = @Iter + 1;
    End

SELECT 'EffRows' = @Iter;
```

this is the best i could compose with my skills, 
as it iterates it's executing each update command(within the while loop) separately as opposed to the select procedure

```
SELECT * FROM ' + @SelectedTableName + ' 
           WHERE RowIndex in (SELECT RowIndex from @TestMulTSELECTViaRowIndexTVPar);'
```

so i don't know if it will best perform as i coded here... 
any comment will be very welcome.

and thanks for your time.